# Measure execution time of windows tasks grouped by name

Tags: windows, powershell, time

I know there are many ways to measure the execution time of a single task invocation, like
`PS> Measure-Command { echo hi }`

But I need to measure the invocation of many tasks with the same name during a build process. In my particular case, I like to measure the **total time** of all executions of `gitversion.exe` during a msbuild run.

Comment: How is `gitversion.exe` being invoked? Do you have a sample project file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: It is invoked from within a ms build task. Here is the link to the documentation. https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/msbuild. I guess you like to invoke the exe indirectly. It should be possible to create an executable that is called gitversion.exe but forwards all arguments to gitversion_real.exe in the same directory. But I wanted to avoid the development if there is a ready solution.

Comment: I don't have any preference, I'm just trying to understand your current setup and requirements :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little application to measure the time of all invocations of a Windows application. See repository for details:

https://github.com/schoetbi/TimerInterceptorExe

Basically, I replace the original executable with a forwarding executable that simultaneously measures the time of the real application.